# Insert into table with where condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables

Table1

```
            OfficeID  OfficeName
            -------------------
            1          UK
            2          JP
            3          US1
            4          US2
            5          US3
            6          US4
```

`OfficeID` is an identity auto increment column.

I need to add couple of more offices (e.g. US5,US6) into `table1`:

```
insert into  Table1 (OfficeName) 
values ('US5'), ('US6')
```

I have another table2

```
            OrgID   OfficeID
            ---------------- 
            1            1
            2            2 
            3            3
            3            4
            3            5
            3            6
```

After inserting the US5 and US6 the new data in table 1 will be

```
            OfficeID  OfficeName
            -------------------
            1          UK
            2          JP
            3          US1
            4          US2
            5          US3
            6          US4
            7          US5
            8          US6
```

After this, I would like to insert `officeID` into table 2 so that my table 2 would look like this:

```
            OrgID   OfficeID
            ---------------- 
            1            1
            2            2 
            3            3
            3            4
            3            5
            3            6 
            3            7
            3            8
```

Here is how I'm trying to do this

```
insert into Table2 (OfficeID) 
    select OfficeID 
    from table1 
    where OfficeID in ((7), (8))
      and table2.OrgID = 3
```

How to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Did you get an error message? What's the problem? Do you mean `Insert into table2 (OrgId, OfficeId) SELECT 3, 7 UNION SELECT 3, 8`?

Comment: What is `OrgID` refer to based on which logic it's got `3` for newly inserted rows?

Comment: Error: the multi part identifier OrgID could not be bound.

Answer (score 2):

You should define all columns you want to insert:

```
         insert into Table2  (OfficeID, OrgID) 
         select OfficeID, 3 from table1 where OfficeID in ((7),(8))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want identity column to be inserted into Table2 try `OUTPUT` clause

```
Insert into Table1 (OfficeName)
    OUTPUT inserted.OfficeID, 3 INTO Table2  (OfficeID, OrgID) 

values
('US5'),
('UK6')
go
```

Answer (score 0):

try to make a inner join to the table 2 because you are trying to filter by column on table 2 and are inaccesable in the select statement, try this

```
 INSERT INTO Table2  (OfficeID) 
 SELECT OfficeID FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON (CLAUSE) WHERE table1.OfficeID in ((7),(8))
 AND   table2.OrgID=3
```

Comment: Your join has no ON clause. This is completely invalid as posted currently.